# Pass view to another activity?

Tags: android

When a user clicks a button in `Main` activity, I startActivityForResult `Second` activity. I would like to pass a view from `Main` to `Second`. I'm not looking to replicate, I want to actually remove the view from `Main` and add it to `Second`, attributes in tact.

I can pack intent extras (strings, ints, etc) with the startActivityForResult but not a View. I've tried passing the view.getId() but can't seem to turn that into a View in `Second`. Any ideas?

Comment: I *really* don't recommend that. I suggest that you get rid of the second activity, if they are so tightly coupled.

Comment: I'd still like to know how it's done.